# PHP: unable to connect to paypal sandbox

Tags: php, ssl, paypal, openssl, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to get a PayPal IPN Script working. But even `fsockopen("ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com")` does not work.

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://google.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 5);
```

`if ($fp)` -> returns true

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 40);
```

`if ($fp)` -> returns false
 and `$errno` is 0

Apache2 log says:

```
 PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout [...]
 PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto [...]
 PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (Unknown error) [...]
```

Edit:
`phpinfo()` says:

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
```

EDIT 2:
got the problem. Its libssl1.0.1c. But how do i downgrade?

Comment: do you have openssl enabled in the php.ini file? nvm :p

Comment: phpinfo says - OpenSSL support: enabled

Comment: No I used https://www.paypaltech.com/SG2/